Can we narrow the scope of this question?
Can we narrow the scope of this question?
Is guadagnarebitcoins a scam?

I found this site:
http://guadagnarebitcoins.altervista.org
What do you think? Is it a scam? Are there ways to earn Bitcoins
  without mining?

This question is attracting spam. I think we should narrow it to be only about whether guadagnarebitcoins is legitimate. There is already a question about where to get free Bitcoins: Where is a comprehensive list of websites for getting free bitcoins?
Thoughts?

Ok, went ahead and did it.
